# How to make using postDelayed from Handler class non-concurrent/parallel. Or in a single thread?

Tags: android, concurrency

This is strange. How come when I postDelay 1000ms, say 1000 times, they seem to run all at the same time?  I was expect it to run every 100ms.  Everything just comes out at all at once right away!

Or do I need to configure something to make it concurrent.  I'm using Android 4.0.

Here is my code:

```
    public void startAniHandler() {

    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override 
        public void run() {
            Log.v("running", "REad image and display handler");

        }
    };

    Handler handler = new Handler(new android.os.Handler.Callback() {
        @Override
        public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
            Log.v("stopping", "handler");
            return false;
        }
    });

    for(int i=0;i<100;i++) {
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
    }


}
```

And my output is:

> 07-09 09:26:20.630      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.630      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.640      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.640      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.640      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.640      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.640      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.660      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.660      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.670      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.670      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.670      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.670      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.690      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.690      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.690      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.700      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.700      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.730      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.730      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.730      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.730      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.740      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.790      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.790      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.790      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.800      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.800      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.800      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.800      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.800      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.800      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.800      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.800      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.800      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.800      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.800      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.810      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.810      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.810      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.810      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.810      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.810      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.810      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.810      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.810      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.810      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.810      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.810      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.810      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.810      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.820      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.820      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.820      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.820      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.820      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.820      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.820      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.820      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.820      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.820      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.820      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.820      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.820      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.820      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.820      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.820      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.820      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.820      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.860      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.860      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.860      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.860      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.860      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.870      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.890      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.910      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.910      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.910      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.920      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.920      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.920      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.920      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.920      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.920      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.930      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.970      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.970      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.970      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.970      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.970      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.970      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.970      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.970      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.980      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.980      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.980      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.980      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.980      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler
>   07-09 09:26:20.980      906-906/com.example.myappLoadingIndicatorWithAnimation V/running﹕ REad image and display handler

Comment: Update: Even if I increasing postDelayed to 10000, the tasks starts right away, I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: That `for` loop will post the `Runnable` taking the **current** time as the start point so all will finish, approximate, at the same time. You probably want something like this: `handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000 + 1000 * i);`

Comment: why didn't you post it as an answer, it is the correct one. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

What Luksprog said worked:

hat for loop will post the Runnable taking the current time as the start point so all will finish, approximate, at the same time. You probably want something like this: handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000 + 1000 * i);